# python program as a command-line tool in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, debian

This is my program folder example:

```
program_name
  main.py
  lib.py
  options.py
```

I want to launch it like this: `program_name args [options]`
from *anywhere* in my Linux os.

Now I already did all the args/options stuff inside my code but actually, I have to `cd` into the folder and launch the file like
`python3 main.py args [options]`

There is a way to do it?
Please don't say things like
`chmod +x`
`#/bin/python for ./filename` or alias stuff related I read all those articles.
I need it to works on boots too.
I studied something for program paths like /usr/local but I never tried.
Did anyone never try that? Or have any solution?

Comment: add `#!/bin/python`,  or whichever path to Python you have. `chmod` it,  then a symbolic link from somewhere on your $PATH will do it

Comment: only my main.py? no problem with dependency files?

Comment: there is a way to use an interpreter with version >= python3.7?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is what you are searching for, but you could just symlink it to your /usr/local/bin like you said, it's safe.
Here's some explainations about where you should symlink in the answer of this post
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116508/adding-to-path-vs-linking-from-bin

I also don't understand why an alias in your .bashrc can't do the trick, it would be easier, but you probably have your reasons.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for +.+, I'll try. Many thanks.